# How can I report opportunity stage to the associated contact and account page?

Tags: custom-object, opportunity

I use Phone Burner and Autopilot. Unfortunately, these programs don't allow dialing or marketing outreach based on opportunity stage. I want to make it so that the opportunity stage is reported to the associated contact and account page as a custom variable.

I can then hopefully use this custom variable and the "stage" of this variable to create custom workflows in Autopilot and Phone Burner. I am really new to this so would appreciate advice on the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are asking here.

It sounds like you are wanting to pull information from "the" Opportunity to display on the related Account.

However, the Account is the parent object and can have zero, one or very many Opportunities. So which one would be displayed on the Account?

Take a look at this data diagram of the relationship between Opportunity, Account and Contact.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by adding a custom field to the Account and then using the process builder to update that field. Keeping in mind what Doug mentioned above that it is possible to have multiple Opportunities related to the Account, the following example assumes you want any Opportunity to update it's parent Account.

[image: Start process from the Opportunity]
[image: Criteria]
[image: Record to Update]

You could then add a formula field to the Contact object to pull down this field - `Account.jjb__Opportunity_Stage__c`